# Does FFTW determine SIMD version dynamically?

Tags: simd, sse, avx, fftw, avx2

For example, if I compile FFTW with AVX2 support and run it in a machine that only have SSE3, would it check and use SSE3 instructions, or just crash immediately?

If it won't dynamically determine SIMD version, I would compile it under a lower target machine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the install docs at https://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/Installation-on-Unix.html

> --enable-sse (single precision), ... and --enable-generic-simd256:
>
> Enable various SIMD instruction sets. You need compiler that supports
> the given SIMD extensions, but FFTW will try to detect at runtime
> whether the CPU supports these extensions. That is, you can compile
> with--enable-avx and **the code will still run on a CPU without AVX
> support.**

I don't know whether it will try multiple lower levels of support if the requested target isn't available.